# Why do I get "NameError: name is not defined" with exec()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scope, python-import, python-exec

When I try this code in a console (in PyCharm):

```
exec("import random")
exec("def f():\n\treturn random.randint(0, 10), random.randint(0, 10)")
locals()['f']()
```

it works fine. But when I try to do exactly the same in my program it doesn't work, and I get the exception

```
NameError: name 'random' is not defined.
```

I found that this code doesn't raise errors:

```
exec("import random", globals(), globals())
exec("def f():\n\treturn random.randint(0, 10), random.randint(0, 10)", globals(), globals())
globals()['f']()
```

But I can't understand why.

What's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not doing "exactly the same" in your program. That exact code, copied verbatim into a file and run as a Python script, works just fine (albeit with no visible result).

What I think you might actually be doing is something like this:

```
def import_stuff():
    exec("import random")

def do_stuff():
    import_stuff()
    exec("def f():\n\treturn random.randint(0, 10), random.randint(0, 10)")
    locals()['f']()

do_stuff()
```

The above code does result in the `NameError` exception noted in your question, because (to quote the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec)),

> In all cases, if the optional parts are omitted, the code is executed in the current scope.

Since the code above imports `random` into the local scope of `import_stuff()`, it's not visible to `do_stuff()`.

In fact, the code above is identical in behaviour to the following:

```
def import_stuff():
    import random

def do_stuff():
    import_stuff()
    def f():
        return random.randint(0, 10), random.randint(0, 10)
    f()

do_stuff()
```

… which also fails, for the same reason.

Assuming this is what's actually going on in your real code, a version modified as in your question by adding `globals(), globals()` arguments to `exec()` would work, because then you're explicitly importing `random` into the global scope, where everything can see it.